# How can I install gcc-7 for Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: nvidia, gcc, cuda, 22.04, tensorflow

I've just installed Ubuntu 22.04, and I'm struggling installing gcc-7. I've already tried with  `sudo apt install gcc-7` but it says there is no installation candidate. I tried to find a PPA for this version but apparently there is none yet.

The reason I need this specific version of gcc is that, according to https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source?hl=es-419#gpu , tensorflow-2.6.0 needs GCC 7.3.1 to be compiled (actually I'm not able to even install CUDA 11.2, the following error appears: *Failed to verify gcc version. See log at /var/log/cuda-installer.log for details.*).

Any help that you can give in this matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674818/ubuntu-20-04-install-gcc-7-3-1

Comment: Already read it but still struggling, I tried installing by `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit-gcc` and then installing CuDNN with the .deb, but after trying to install tensorflow in a conda environment via `pip tensorflow` I get:
_Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform._

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install gcc7 on ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406962/install-gcc7-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406962/install-gcc7-on-ubuntu-22-04