# Install gcc7 on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gcc, 22.04

I would like to install gcc-7 on Ubuntu 22.04.

I used:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-7 g++-7
```

But got the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package g++-7 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package gcc-7 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gcc-7' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'g++-7' has no installation can
```

How can I install it on my machine?

Kind regards

didate

Comment: GCC7 is the default in 18.04. For 22.04, the default is GCC11, and GCC7 is not available for obvious reasons.

Comment: But is it possible for me to install it?

Comment: It is not impossible, but might not be a good idea for 22.04. Also, something installed, doesn't mean it is going to work.

Comment: You can have as many versions of gcc as you want, installed at the same time. ..... Using examples : `export CC=gcc-7 CXX=g++-7 && [command]` ...... and `CC=gcc-7 CXX=g++-7 cmake ../` ......... Add a (temporary) line to "sources.list" : `deb [url] focal main universe` to install `g++-7`

Answer (score 12):

Thanks @Knud Larsen for that solution.

I had the same problem, I need the old version for the distcc server. The client system, a weak industrial PC cannot be updated.

So the solution is simple, I didn't think of it, but it works. For the records, I added:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe
```

to /etc/apt/sources.list and

ran: `apt update; apt install g++-7`

Comment: please how to add deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe to /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: @daren-2022 Edit that file to add this line. Since it is a system file, you will need sudo.

Comment: For anyone who see this, **please be careful doing this.** Mixing two versions of Ubuntu on the same installation can be a Really Bad Idea (though admittedly I've been guilty of doing it in some instances). I don't easily imagine this going wrong, but doing stuff like this can explode on you.

Comment: It's critical, of course, and it won't work well for most other packages. It will only work for packages that are already designed to be installed in different versions at the same time, like gcc, g++, qt, etc. I have therefore removed this line from /etc/apt/sources.list after installing the minor version of g++ to avoid further problems and also to speed up "apt update"

Answer (score 0):

I would reccommend installing `gcc-7` with `brew`.
That way, it is not permanently added to your system and you can remove it when you no longer need it.

Just run `brew install gcc@7`

However, DO NOT USE BREW for anything that requires admin rights.
It will not work.

Comment: Linuxbrew, unlike Homebrew on macOS, installs packages in system-wide directories by default. Even if you're the only user, these directories require root access for modification, so using sudo before `brew install` ensures the installation works correctly and avoids permission errors.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1338512)

Comment: @karel, I think you are mistaken; Brew does not require sudo, except for installation.

Comment: @pzkpfw This does answer the question. I found a way to install gcc-7 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: @Langdon What I wrote was "using `sudo` before brew install ensures the installation works correctly and avoids permission errors"  so  there's no contradiction between you and me there.

Comment: Just use `sudo apt` for sudo packages.